# Conky only appears in first tag in awesome?

Tags: linux, tags, awesome-wm, conky

When I start conky in my awesome desktop environment, conky only shows up in my first tag.

Same situation occurs when I start `pcmanfm` with `--desktop` params.

Only first tag has a `Desktop`, but the others have not... Anybody knows why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me when I remove `sticky` from the `own_window_hints` line in conkyrc, so adding it should fix your problem.

```
own_window_hints undecorated,below,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,sticky
```

You probably want to have a look at [this page](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Conky_bar) in the awesome doc.